# Autoform insert no restrictions

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

I'm trying to create a public autoform that gathers data. As a result, the people using the form don't have userIds. How do I create an insert form with no restrictions?

This is what I've previously used however it requires as user to be registered.

```
Collection.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return !!userId;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change it to this:

```
Collection.allow({
  insert: true,
});
```

Basically it allows anyone to insert a record to  your database.

Comment: I'm not sure why your solution didn't work, however adding in `insert: function(doc) {
    return true;
  }` makes it work. Thanks Mikkel.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I did wonder if an explicit return was needed :)

Comment: All good. As soon as I saw it the penny dropped so thanks again.